# Measure real distance between two points using iOS Depth camera

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, distance, arkit, truedepth-camera

Right now I'm exploring features of `iOS Depth camera` and now I want to obtain the distance in real-world metrics between two points (for example, between two eyes).

I have successfully connected `iOS Depth camera` functionality and I have `AVDepthData` in my hands but I'm not quite sure how I can get a real-world distance between two specific points.

I believe I could calculate it if I have depth and viewing angle, but I don't see that the latter is presented as parameter. Also I know that this task could be handled with `ARKit`, but I'm really curious how I can implement it myself. I mean `ARKit` uses Depth camera as well, so there must be an algorithm where Depth maps is all I need to calculate the real distance

Could you please give me an advice how to tackle this task? Thanks in advance!